# Specific animation effect for last and first page ViewPager

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

Tell me, who knows how can I make the effect for the viewPager, for example, at the zero position when scrolling to the left turns false departure of the item on some part, when - releasing-return (I do not know how this effect is called).

**EDIT**

[Added media](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ghyc3vANNP6k2RBfLSXvj5K3d_ApQDtu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: do you have some visuals?

Comment: @RahulKumar , I shared the video.

Comment: needs permission to open the file.

Comment: @RahulKumar, edited once more to public access